# How to input attribute into the webtestclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I have a controller in which it fetches a value from the attribute map.

The code responsible for fetching something in the attributes is this:

```
Map<String, Object> memberClaims = (Map<String, Object>) request.getAttribute("token");
```

And in my test this is how I've wired it up:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldReturn200()
   {
      webTestClient.post()
                   .uri(URL)
                   .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                   .body(Mono.just(order()), Token.class)
                   .attribute("token", "123abc")
                   .exchange()
                   .expectStatus()
                   .is2xxSuccessful();

   }
```

But the .attribute seems to not have any effect. I've debugged and can see that the token map is not in the MockHttpServletRequest.. thus the test returns a 500 server response.. null pointer.

Anyone know how i can add attributes to the mock request?

Answer (score 1):

You must be aware that `.attribute(String, String)` is not intended to send parameters from the client along with the request. It is used to put additional attributes to a request when it is already on server side.
An example would be if you have an interceptor in Spring adding further information after grabbing the request an forwarding the request afterwards. This is well explained [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-attribute.html):

To send '*attributes*' from the client side you have to add them as *parameters* as in this example:

```
var respSpec = webTestClient.post()
      .uri( uriBuilder - > uriBuilder
        .scheme("http")
        .host("localhost")
        .port("10080")
        .path("/endpoint")
        .queryParam("requestId", requestId)
        .queryParam("aUrl", aUrl)
        .build())
      .header(apiSecretHeader, secret)
      .header("HEADER_1", "header value 1")
      .header("HEADER_2", "header value 2")
      .exchange();
```

The REST endpoint could be defined this way:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/endpoint", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public ResponseEntity<?> myEndpoint(@RequestParam final String requestId, @NonNull @RequestParam(name = "url") final URL aUrl)
```